# Getting Null Values in Spring Native Query Project

Tags: spring-boot, postman, nativequery

*This is my Data Repository file and i used native query to retrieve all data address(Locations) of Data. I called the function using Postman and I got null outputs of locations. This my first time of using Native query and its really impossible to solve these errors*

**DataRepository**

```
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT dataAddress FROM Data")
    List<DataProject> getDataAddress();
}
```

**DataServiceImpl**

```
    public List<DataProject> getDataAddress() {
        return dataRepository.getDataAddress();
    }
```

**DataService**

```
List<DataProject> getDataAddress();
```

**DataModel**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CCCData")
public class Data {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long dataId;

    @Column(name = "DATA_NAME")
    private String dataName;

    @Column(name ="DATA_ADDRESS")
    private String dataAddress;

    @Column(name = "DATA_DESC")
    private String dataDesc;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date dateOfCreated;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date dateOfUpdated;

    public long getDataId() {
        return dataId;
    }

    public void setDataId(long dataId) {
        this.dataId = dataId;
    }

    public String getDataName() {
        return dataName;
    }

    public void setDataName(String dataName) {
        this.dataName = dataName;
    }

    public String getDataAddress() {
        return dataAddress;
    }

    public void setDataAddress(String dataAddress) {
        this.dataAddress = dataAddress;
    }

    public String getDataDesc() {
        return dataDesc;
    }

    public void setDataDesc(String dataDesc) {
        this.dataDesc = dataDesc;
    }

    public Date getDateOfCreated() {
        return dateOfCreated;
    }

    public void setDateOfCreated(Date dateOfCreated) {
        this.dateOfCreated = dateOfCreated;
    }

    public Date getDateOfUpdated() {
        return dateOfUpdated;
    }

    public void setDateOfUpdated(Date dateOfUpdated) {
        this.dateOfUpdated = dateOfUpdated;
    }
```

**DataProjection**

```
public interface DataProject {

    String getDataAddress();
}
```

**DataController**

```
@GetMapping("/data/locations")
    public List<DataProject> getDataAddress() {
        return dataService.getDataAddress();
    }
```

**Postman Output**

```
[
    {
        "dataAddress": null
    },
    {
        "dataAddress": null
    },
    {
        "dataAddress": null
    },
    {
        "dataAddress": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring won't return you only address using below query. It still return you `DATA` object

```
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT dataAddress FROM Data")
    List<DataProject> getDataAddress();
}
```

for fetching only `DataAddress` you need to create a constructor inside `Data` model for `DataAddress` only

```
public Data(String dataAddress) {
    this.dataAddress = dataAddress;
}
```

and your query will look like this:

```
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT new Data(dataAddress) FROM Data")
    List<DataProject> getDataAddress();
}
```

Update 1 :

if you need this for other fields with same datatype and then above 'constructor' based method fails. There are some other alternatives:

> You can fetch `DATA` object and use java stream map function to extract only 1 field. `data.stream().map((data) -> data.getDataAddress()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

> You can use native SQL query to fetch only required fields.
> `@Query(value = "SELECT d.data_address FROM CCCData d", nativeQuery=true)`

Comment: you can create as many constructor in `DATA` class. Make sure to create a blank constructor also.

Comment: Thank you for your great advises and my problem is solved. Thank You again!!

Comment: Hello Aman Garg, What I need to do when i wanted to get only another value like "dataName". I need two functions. 1). to get dataAddress,   2). to get dataName

Comment: that's not possible, your constructor will conflict. create a different constructor.

Comment: Thank you and again i'm getting null values

Comment: `public CCCData(String dataAddressProvince) {
        this.dataAddressProvince = dataAddressProvince;
    }

    public CCCData() {
    }
`

Comment: `
@Query(value = "SELECT d.DATA_ADDRESS_PROVINCE FROM CCCData d", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DataProject> getDataAddressProvince();
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217430/discussion-between-chamikamac-and-aman-garg).